# Sequence of measurable sets converges to zero

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f,g \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$. And we define for all $p\geq 1$, $(A_p)_p\subset \mathcal{M}$ sequence of measurable sets such that $A_p \subset [0,T]$ and
$$\mu(A_p)\rightarrow 0 \,\,\,\,(p\rightarrow0).$$
And let $x_p,x \in C^1([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $(x_p)_p$ converges towards $x$ uniformly.

Can we say that :
$\frac{1}{\mu(A_p)}\int_{A_p} ||g(x_p)-f(x_p)||_{\mathbb{R}^n}ds \rightarrow 0?$

Comment: There seems to be a problem with how you're defining either $f$ and $g$ or $x_n$. Also, the norm should be an absolute value?

Comment: You are also using $n$ for a running index as well the dimension of the Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Let $x_k=x$ for all $n$ and $A_k=(t-\frac  1 k, t +\frac 1 k)$. Then $\frac 1 {\mu (A_k)} \int_{A_k} |g(x_k(s))-f(x_k(s))|ds \to |g(x(t))-f(x(t))|$ as $ k \to \infty$.